# What makes returning a reference String in rust a dangling pointer?

Tags: pointers, rust, memory-leaks

```rust
fn dangle() -> &String { // dangle returns a reference to a String

    let s = String::from("hello"); // s is a new String

    &s // we return a reference to the String, s
}
```

Going through rust book and learning about ownership, How does returning a reference to a String make it a dangling pointer?

Comment: This code can't compile because the local variable s is automatically deleted at end of scope (ie function) and you can't thus point to it.

Comment: A "dangling pointer" or "dangling reference" is a programming idiom that means reference to deallocated data. Since `s` has a clearly defined scope that ends with the end of the function, its data will be deallocated when the function returns. This is why a reference to the string (or to the data inside the string) would be "dangling" when returned from the function.

Comment: Also, your question has a "memory-leaks" tag. A dangling reference is the _inverse_ of a memory leak, it's a use-after-free. In other words, with a dangling reference the data is deallocated too early, not too late.

Answer (score 2):

The string you're referencing lives inside the function (only). That means, that the management code to allocate and deallocate memory for this string will be put into this function by the compiler. Therefore the compiler has to deallocate the memory for s before returning to the caller. However, `&s` would now reference a deallocated item, that is a dangling pointer.